# Meteor 0.7.1.1 handlebar conditioning in attributes

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Handlebar conditioning seems not to be working in attributes.

in the .js

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
Template.cards.myCards = function()
{
    return ["something.png"];
}
    Template.card.isSelected = function()
    {
    return true;
    };
}
```

in the .html

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{>cards}}
</body>

<template name="cards">
    {{#each myCards}}
        {{>card}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="card">
    <div class="{{#if isSelected}}selectedClass{{/if}}">
        {{#if isSelected}}selectedContent{{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Gives me (once rendered)

```
<div class="&lt;!--data:DQhTaW3zefLpaZQ2k--&gt;">
        selectedContent
</div>
```

Where is my "selectedClass" gone ? Why is it replaced by the commented data block ?

Take the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Xample/meteor-issue-handlebarattribute)

Comment: Can you include all your relevant code? By default, handlebars will automatically escape special characters. You can use triple brackets to override this behavior.

Comment: It renders fine for me with the same meteor version. Are you actually using html or an html preprocessor (jade, blade, etc.)?

Comment: @DavidWeldon There is no preprocessor, as I do now suspect a rendering bug I updated the question with the minimum code to reproduce the problem. Also this still does not work in 0.7.1.1

Comment: @BradM code updated, I thought about using triple brackets but it is not relevant in this case. Note that the problem only happened once the card template in rendered inside another template within an each function.

Comment: Interesting. Taken out of the `each` it works fine. This seems like a bug. Did you try it with the new rendering engine?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I took the regular "out of the box" Meteor rendering engine. Which rendering are you talking about? [The sortable one ?](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/09/13/previewing-meteors-new-rendering-engine-reactive-sortable-lists) If so, no I never tried it neither know where to get it actually. I reported the [issue to meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1867) #1867

Comment: @DavidWeldon the new rendering engine is working correctly, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem recognised as a bug and [issue closed](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1867) the problem has been fixed in Blaze